# Anyone know of a nusach that exludes the word לברך from the prayer of ובמקהלות?

Tags: tefilla, nuschaot

Anyone know of a nusach that exludes the word לברך from the prayer of ובמקהלות?

It seems to be in both Ashkenaz and Sefard

Comment: More background please. You ask for a nusach but you say "It seems to be in both Ashkenaz and Sefard". How do you know that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, לברך doesn't appear in many non-Ashkenazi siddurim. For example, Sefaria's [Edot Hamizrach](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Edot_HaMizrach%2C_Shabbat_Shacharit%2C_Pesukei_D%27Zimra.28?lang=bi) siddur omits it, the de Sola Pool siddur omits it, and I've checked my own Yemenite (both Shami and Baladi) and Egyptian Sepharadi siddurim to see the same.

Additionally, the Reform siddur Mishkan Tefillah omits it (it has significantly abridged the paragraph that starts with ובמקהלות).

Comment: Sefaria's Sfard had it, but from the siddurim I have checked, those without לברך have לנצח instead. I saw a quotation of this tefillah in a sefer without לברך or לנצח

Comment: Where did you see this?